# image upload with external url in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, image-processing, cloudinary

```
var uploadPAN = app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
 
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path,
    {
      ocr: "adv_ocr"
    }, function(error, result) {
        if( result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.status === "complete" ) {
          res.json(result); 
          var desp=(result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.data[0].textAnnotations[0].description);
}
   }
});
```

So currently this code uploads the image from local.

**So my question is:**

How to upload with an image url?

Suppose I have the url-> `www.xyzasdfghjkl.png`, then what would be the path and image in `req.files.image.path`

Comment: Does there a way to do this>

Answer (score -1):

In order to upload an image from the web, you can just add the url as your image path.

For example:
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("www.xyzasdfghjkl.png", function(error, result) { console.log(result); });

Comment: The intention may be to completely migrate the file to another server